# get '' and root to aren't identical in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this code in my Rails 5 app:

```
namespace :admin do
  get '' => "my_controller#index"   # works
```

But this

```
namespace :admin do
  root to: "my_controller#index" # error
```

somehow causes a React component I use in my project throw an exception.

The exception being

> 'admin' route doesn't exist/not found.

**That implies that the two aren't identical.** What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 5.2, the only obvious difference I see is with the named URL helpers that are generated.

Given:

```
namespace :admin do
  get '' => 'my_controller#index'
  root to: 'my_controller#index'
end
```

The resulting routes are:

```
     admin GET /admin(.:format) admin/my_controller#index
admin_root GET /admin(.:format) admin/my_controller#index
```

Without knowing more about how your React App generates its URLs, I would say this is the most likely cause of the discrepancy.  As far as I can tell, they are otherwise identical.